# IntegrityError at /images/create/ - NOT NULL constraint failed: images_image.user_id

Tags: python, django

I tried getting an image via its URL and saving it to the database but I get **IntegrityError at /images/create/ - NOT NULL constraint failed: images_image.user_id** thrown at me. Here are files that could be concerned

**models.py**

(containing code to override the `save()` method to automatically generate the `slug` field based on the value of the `title` field)

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Image(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='images_created')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    url = models.URLField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d')
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    users_like = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
    related_name='images_liked', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
            super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**forms.py**

(containing code to override the `save()` method to retrieve a given image and save it)

```
from urllib import request
from django import forms
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.utils.text import slugify
from .models import Image

class ImageCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('title', 'url', 'description')
        widgets = {
            'url' : forms.HiddenInput,
        }

    def clean_url(self):
        url = self.cleaned_data['url']
        valid_extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg']
        extension = url.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower()
        if extension not in valid_extensions:
            raise forms.ValidationError('the given URL doesn\'t match valid image extensions')
        return url

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
        image = super(ImageCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
        image_url = self.cleaned_data['url']
        image_name = '{}.{}'.format(slugify(image.title),
        image_url.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower())

        # Download image from given URL
        response = request.urlopen(image_url)
        image.image.save(image_name, ContentFile(response.read()))

        if commit:
            image.save()
        return image
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import ImageCreateForm

@login_required
def image_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Form is sent
        form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Form data is valid
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            new_item = form.save(commit=False)

            # Assign current user to the item
            new_item.user = request.user
            new_item.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Image added successfully')

            # Redirect to the newly created item detail view
            return redirect(new_item.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        # Build form with data provided by the bookmarklet via GET
        form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.GET)

    return render(request, 'images/image/create.html',
    {'section' : 'images', 'form' : form})
```

What's wrong? Somebody help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you trouble in the form `save` method, when you try to save image, django need to save instance, so you have an error, my solution is add user to form data:

in form

```
class ImageCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = ('title', 'url', 'description', 'user')
        widgets = {
            'url': forms.HiddenInput,
            'user': forms.HiddenInput,
        }
```

in view

```
# Form is sent
data = request.POST.copy()
data.update({'user': request.user.pk })
form = ImageCreateForm(data=data)
if form.is_valid():
    # Form data is valid
    new_item = form.save()
    messages.success(request, 'Image added successfully')
    # Redirect to the newly created item detail view
    return redirect(new_item.get_absolute_url())
```

Comment: you need add field `user` to the form, sorry i don't saw it

Comment: glad to help you)